# How to load/add third party jar files to bitbucket?

Tags: java, git, maven, bitbucket

I want to load some jar file that are not present in maven repository or any other such repository.

For that I have created a repository named as "maven-repo" on bitbucket and cloned it to my local machine.

Now I am using command

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=groupid -DartifactId=myid
>   -Dversion=5.1 -Dfile=/path to file/filename.jar -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DlocalRepositoryPath=./repository  -DcreateChecksum=true

After that I push that folder/repository to bitbucket server.
Now I want to add it to my maven project's pom.xml.

I added like:

```
<repository>
    <id>Hyperv </id>
    <url>https://myurl/repository/</url>
</repository>
```

But it gives me error failed to load a jar.

How to include a jar file and import classes in project???

Comment: Use a repository manager like Artifactory, Nexus or Archiva and deploy the artifacts there. Apart from that to deploy artifacts into a remote repository you need to use `mvn deploy:deploy-file ...` instead of `mvn install:install-file` which installs only into local repo `$HOME/.m2/repository`. Furthermore which error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

### Deploying with Maven

From official documentation (I cannot link, this is a popup)

> Bintray adds a new layer to traditional Maven repositories in the form of a package.
>   A package acts as container for managing metadata about your project and its versions and may contain a collections of artifacts with different group ids.
>
> When uploading files to a repository, you can associate them with specific package and version information in various ways:
>
> **Deploying to this repository**
>
> Please go into a specific package in this repository to see how to set up Maven to deploy artifacts to that package.
>
> 1. In Maven’s setting.xml file, add the following section to declare your Bintray credentials. Use your API key as your password (not your login password, please!):
>
>    ```
>    <server>
>        <id>bintray-user-package-package</id>
>        <username>user</username>
>        <password>**********</password>
>    </server>
>    ```
> 2. Add the the following Distribution Management section to your project’s pom.xml file to tell Maven to deploy into this package using the credentials you configured in the previous step:
>
>    ```
>    <distributionManagement>
>       <repository>
>           <id>bintray-user-repo-package</id>
>           <name>user-repo-package</name>
>           <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/repo/package</url>
>       </repository>
>    </distributionManagement>
>    ```

### Manual deploy

Prepare artifact folder as is described in [How Do I Upload My Stuff to Bintray?](https://bintray.com/docs/bintrayuserguide.html#_how_do_i_upload_my_stuff_to_bintray)

And deploy using commannd like this

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=myfile-0.1.pom  -Dfile=myfile-0.1.jar -DrepositoryId=bintray -Durl=https://api.bintray.com/maven/user/repo/package
```

In general deploying with maven is much easier